# Using SSIS and T-SQL to convert date to dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, ssis

When I use T-SQL to convert a datetime into **dd.mm.yyyy** for an csv output using SSIS, the file is produced with a dd-mm-yyyy **hh:mm:ss** which is not what i need.

I am using:

```
convert(varchar,dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TNCY-START],104)
```

which appears correct in SSMS.

Which is the best way to handle the conversion to be output from SSIS?
Not as simple as i thought it would be.

Comment: Give us the steps necessary to reproduce the issue.   I have no idea what you are actually doing to get the results you say you are getting.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Where does that value come from? If it comes from a SQL query, why not use that conversion in the query itself? In any case, you want to *convert* a datetime to a string. This means you need to add a conversion. What formula did you use there? Are you storing the *original* value perhaps, instead of the formatted one?

Comment: Finally, it's probably better to set the *locale* of the Flat File connection manager than trying to convert dates and decimals on the fly.

Comment: Aside: From [`VarChar(n)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "When _n_ is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When _n_ is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30." The best practice is to _always_ specify a length.

Comment: Just specify the length =10: `convert(varchar(10),dbo.[RE-TENANCY].[TNCY-START],104)`

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.

Using your query as a framework for driving the package

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(char(10),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,104) AS DayMonthYearDate
```

I explicitly declared a length for our dd.mm.yyyy value and since it's always going to be 10 characters, let's use a data type that reflects that.

Run the query, you can see it correctly produces 13.02.2019

In SSIS, I added an OLE DB Source to the data flow and pasted in my query

[image]

I wired up a flat file destination and ran the package. As expected, the string that was generated by the query entered the data flow and landed in the output file as expected.

[image]

If you're experiencing otherwise, the first place I'd check is double clicking the line between your source and the next component and choose Metadata. Look at what is reported for the tenancy start column. If it doesn't indicate dt_str/dt_wstr then SSIS thinks the data type is date variant and is applying locale specific rules to the format. You might also need to check how the column is defined in the flat file connection manager.

Answer (score 1):

The most precise control on output format of the date can be achieved by T-SQL  `FORMAT()`. It is available since SQL Server 2012. 
It is slightly [slower](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but) than CONVERT() but gives desired flexibility
An example:

```
SELECT TOP 4
       name,
       FORMAT(create_date, 'dd.MM.yyyy') AS create_date
FROM sys.databases;


name    create_date
--------------------
master  08.04.2003
tempdb  12.02.2019
model   08.04.2003
msdb    30.04.2016
```

p.s. take into account that `FORMAT()` produces NVARCHAR output, which is different from your initial conversation logic, therefore extra cast to VARCHAR(10)) perhaps will be necessary to apply